# Row versioning in MySQL

Tags: mysql, versioning, innodb, database-versioning

I would like to include an integer version field in my table, auto-incrementing on each update made to a row. Is it possible to do this in MySQL?

Please note that I'm not talking about a `TIMESTAMP`, which is not reliable as two concurrent updates might happen during the same second.

Comment: What is the use exactly? All it will tell you is the number of times a particular row has been updated. You can't revert to a previous version.

Comment: It would be used for versioning entities in an ORM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way (I can think of) to do this is a (before-update) trigger that automatically increments the column value.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is. The more general problem is called [slowly changing dimensions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowly_changing_dimension).

Comment: Interesting reading, but not answering the specific question. Or should I rephrase my question: *how* to do it? :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6318317/temporal-database-design-with-a-twist-live-vs-draft-rows